# Why does PrintStream extend FilterOutputStream and not OutputStream?

Tags: java

`System.out` and `System.err` are both `PrintStream`s; and `PrintStream` extends `FilterOutputStream`.

From the `FilterOutputStream`'s javadoc:

> This class is the superclass of all classes that filter output streams. These streams sit on top of an already existing output stream (the underlying output stream) which it uses as its basic sink of data, but possibly transforming the data along the way or providing additional functionality.
>
> **The class FilterOutputStream itself simply overrides all methods of OutputStream with versions that pass all requests to the underlying output stream**. Subclasses of FilterOutputStream may further override some of these methods as well as provide additional methods and fields.

(emphasis mine)

`FilterOutputStream` itself extends `OutputStream`.

I am at a loss here. Is there any reason why `PrintStream` needs to extend `FilterOutputStream` instead of `OutputStream`?

Sample code appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any higher level Stream that needs to filter the input or output of a nested lower-level Stream, needs to first extend FilteredOutputStream, and the same is true for InputStreams. So it makes sense that ***all*** of the higher-level OutputStreams extend the FilteredOutputStream class, in other words, all Streams that allow for and in fact require the nesting of other Streams to function, must extend this class.

I don't know what the class does internally, but I imagine it somehow massages the data to allow the higher level streams to be able to make sense out of them. To know more, I'm guessing that you're going to have to delve into the source code.

Comment: I think that PrintStream extends FilterOutputStream to make some additional operations and calculations about characters and their encodings. One cannot mix characters (strings) and binary data in the same PrintStream and that can be a clue.

Answer (score 2):

`FilterOutputStream` applies the composition pattern where it delegates all the calls to its instance variable `out`:

```
/* The underlying output stream to be filtered. */
protected OutputStream out;
```

`FilterOutputStream` also has default implementations for the abstract class `OutputStream`:

```
public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    out.write(b);
}

public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
    write(b, 0, b.length);
}

public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if ((off | len | (b.length - (len + off)) | (off + len)) < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
        write(b[off + i]);
    }
}

public void flush() throws IOException {
    out.flush();
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Now, any class including `PrintStream` can extend `FilterOutputStream` and override the appropriate methods. Note that they still need to delegate their calls to `out`. For example `PrintStream#flush()`:

```
public void flush() {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            ensureOpen();
            out.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            trouble = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The PrintStream must implement various filters, handling character encodings, and most ultimately, printing non-character data as characters.

The general contract of FilterOutputStream fits this best, so that is the class used.

Comment: What you are basically telling here is that `FilterOutputStream` does composition?

Comment: @fge It may handle any sort of filtering or changes to data, in this case character handling or composition.